# Complete my number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Can you complete following number sequence ?

> 389919, 1308, 93, ?, ?

Hint:

> mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be:

> 389919, 1308, 93, 12, 3

Because:

> $389 + 919 = 1308$, the number $919$ is mirrored, but is still the same. $13 + 80 = 93$, here $08$ gets mirrored. So you have to mirror the numbers second half and add it to the first half.